# Location of OpenCV & haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml

Tags: opencv, jupyter-notebook, cascade-classifier

I am working with image processing using OpenCV. I have installed OopenCV 3.3.0 in Conda. I would like to find out the full path where my OpenCV is installed and where haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml is located. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's in the directory `etc/haarcascades` inside the OpenCV `build` directory